# Azure AD B2C - Force user to change password on first login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a built in sign in user flow for users to sign in.

I am creating users thru power shell script where i have used ForceChangePasswordNextLogin to true. I was expecting users will be shown password change page when they login for the first time, but i always get "Password Expired" error.
Could anyone provide some inputs on this ?

Answer (score 3):

As per Mar 2023 it is possible using user flows.

1. Create the user using Graph API and set `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true` and assign him a temporary password
2. On the Azure B2C portal, go to your signin flow
3. In the sing in flow Go to Settings-> Properties
4. Check the "Forced password reset" checkbox

[image]

And next time user will sign in he will redirect to choose new password

Answer (score 1):

While creating local accounts in B2C via Graph API/powershell, the `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` property must be set to `false`. This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#password-profile-property. This generates a temporary password, which is marked as expired and requires the user to provide a new password. Since, in Azure AD B2C there is a different mechanism for resetting password (i.e. by using Password Reset User flows/Custom Policies), users don't get the option to reset the password and only get **The password has expired**. message. In B2C, administrator accounts cannot be used to reset password or set `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true` for consumer accounts.

As of now, the only possible way to require users to reset their passwords at first logon is by using custom policy: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon.

Comment: I am using power shell script to create users.  It seems there is no forceChangePasswordNextSignIn  property as script giving an error.

Comment: With power shell please try with `ForceChangePasswordNextLogin`

Comment: Tried , no luck. I always get Password Expried error.

Comment: as i already suggested in the answer. This process will generate temp password which is marked as password expired. The only possible way for users to reset their passwords at first logon is by using custom policy